# ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end in AngularJs is not working for particular user only in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have table which list items with the phases like in below example. The issue is the heading is repeated for each items in that phase. This issue is happening only for particular user, the user is using the same chrome version as the other user and it is working fine in other browser of his system.

```
column1 column2 column3
phase1
item1.1.1 item1.1.2 item1.1.3 
item1.2 item1.2.1 item1.2.3
...
phase2
item2.1.1 item2.1.2 item2.1.3
item2.2.1 item2.2.2 item2.2.3
```

I am using angularjs, in the table i am using like this for to render the above scenario

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="heading in headings">
     {{heading}}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="phase in phases">
      <td>{{phase.heading}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>phase.item(column1)</td>
      <td>phase.item(column2)</td> and so on
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The isssue is, the phase heading is repeated for every item in its phase.
eg:

```
column1 column2 column3
phase1
item1.1.1 item1.1.2 item1.1.3 
phase1
item1.2 item1.2.1 item1.2.3
...
phase2
item2.1.1 item2.1.2 item2.1.3
phase2
item2.2.1 item2.2.2 item2.2.3
```

Comment: And i found that there is a condition for the phase heading which disable the heading part if the previous one got the same phase heading. 
`if(($index==0) || getPreviousphaseheading(phase).phase.name == phase.heading.name)`
I suspect this condition